# UIScrollView not showing first object

Tags: uiscrollview, nsmutablearray

I currently have a scroll view loading images from an array, here's my code:

```
icons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"one" ofType:@"png"]], [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"two" ofType:@"png"]], [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"three" ofType:@"png"]],nil];

int numberOfItems = [icons count];
NSLog(@"Number of objects: %i",numberOfItems);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {

    if (i <= 3) {

        finalFrame = CGRectMake( i*(80), 12, 80, 80);
    }

    UIButton *iconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    iconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    iconButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 57);
    iconButton.center = CGPointMake(40, 29);
    iconButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [iconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    iconButton.tag = i;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *icon = [icons objectAtIndex:i];
          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [iconButton setImage:icon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });
    });

    [sub addSubview:iconButton];

    sub = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:finalFrame];
    [scrollView addSubview:sub];
}
```

The NSLog reads 3 objects, but my scroll view is only showing 2 of them, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your code give right number of object?

Comment: Yep, the log reads three objects in the array, which there are.

Answer (score 1):

I think in it is in for loop for it should be like this

```
(int i = 0; i <= numberOfItems; i++)
```

Comment: Nope, after seeing your answer I thought u were right but then once I changed it it threw an exceeded index error.